# Migrating to Rails 3.2 - Undefined method 'session=' for ActionController::Base:Class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I migrated an old Ruby (1.8.7) and Rails (2.2.2) application to Ruby (1.9.3) and Rails (3.2.12) following all of these excellent references:

[Rails Upgrade Script](http://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git)
[Rails 3 Migration Blog](http://blog.wolfman.com/articles/2010/12/17/upgrading-a-rails-2-dot-2-2-app-to-rails-3)
[Booting the Rails 3 App](http://gregmoreno.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/rails-3-upgrade-part-1-booting-the-application/)

I am able to start up the app's Rails server but when I access the app via the browser, and then BLAMMO! I get a server error:

**!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `session=' for ActionController::Base:Class**

When I grep -r for "session =" I get:

```
/var/www/vendor_sandbox/config/application.rb:    config.action_controller.session = {
/var/www/vendor_sandbox/config/environment.rb.rails2:  config.action_controller.session = {
/var/www/vendor_sandbox/destroy/config/environment.rb:  config.action_controller.session = {
/var/www/vendor_sandbox/generate/config/environment.rb:  config.action_controller.session = {
```

According to a Google search for that error, it's an old issue from Rails 2 so I'm wondering If I missed something in the migration process or if this is something else. Thanks

Here is my terminal session activity:

```
root@partners:/var/www/vendor_sandbox# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [i686-linux]
root@partners:/var/www/vendor_sandbox# rails --version
Rails 3.2.12
root@partners:/var/www/vendor_sandbox# rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on     http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

**Then, I hit the application from a browser and:**

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `session=' for ActionController::Base:Class
```

Comment: You used to be able to say session :off to turn off the session (which isn't needed these days), but without seeing the code that's just a guess

Comment: OK. I will grep around for "session" and see what turns up. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `config.session_store` instead. You'll have to specify the store type, most likely `:cookie_store`. Here's an example of what it will look like in your `application.rb`

```
config.session_store(:cookie_store, {:key => foo, :secret => bar})
```

Whatever options you had after the `session=` will go inside that hash there.

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks. I changed the syntax from "config.action_controller.session = {...}" to the newer syntax. All is better.